# Prove that every component is complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let G be a simple graph in which for every three vertices
> $u,v,w$ we have:
>
> - between those three vertices none of them are neighbors,
> - or they form triangle
> - or only two of them are neighbors.
>
> Prove that every connected component of this graph is complete graph.

First, I am not sure what does it mean that only two of them are neighbors. Does it mean that from 3 possible edges between those three vertices only one of them exists, for example edge $e=uv$?
Then, I tried to assume the opposite, that there exists compoenent H that is not complete graph, and number of vertices in H is $\ge 1$. Now if we pick two vertices $u,v$ from H(such that $u,v$ are not neighbors because H is not complete so those two vertices exist) and $w$ from component other than H, first claim would be fulfilled, and other two won't, but that is not contradiction. Where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $v$ with maximal number set of neighbors $N$. Then, every two in $N$ must be conected, so $N_v:=N\cup \{v\}$ is complete graph. Let $N_v$ be in a component $C$.

Suppose exists $w\in C\setminus N_v$. Then there is path from $v$ to $w$ and let $u$ be first vertex on this path (going from $v$) not in $N_v$. Then $u$ is neighbor of some $s\in N_v$ which means $s$ has bigger degree than $v$. A contradiction, so $C = N_v$.

Now you repeat the process (take vertex with maximal degree in $G\setminus C$) until you are left out of vertices.

Comment: So $v$ is actually vertex of maximum degree, right? And do you mind explaining second part, not sure what is $u$ and why it has to be neighbor with $s$?

Comment: Also, where we used three claims from the begging? And why $u$ is not in $N_v$?

Comment: It is clearer now. So the vertex $s$ actually has degree larger than every vertex in $N_v$ right, not just $v$ because every vertex in N is the same degree as v?

Comment: And, one more question is how we used 3 claims from the begging of task?

Comment: Yes, $s$ has larger degree than $v$ and every vertex in $N_v$ has degree as $v$.

Comment: You mean first one, because none of u,v and w are neighbors?

Comment: And still not sure why u has to bee neighbor of s?

Comment: $u$ is on a path from $v$ to $w$. This path starts at in $N_v$ at $v$. Suner or later there is first point on this path which is not in $N_v$, since $w$ is not in $N_v$. But then vertex before $u$ on this path must be in $N_v$.

Comment: Ok, and last one :), how we used third condition here, what two vertices are neighbors here?

Comment: we use it in deducing $N_v$ is clique. Actually here is where we needed 2. and 3. condition.

Comment: So triangle exists because $N_v$ is complete graph and every three vertices from it form triangle. And 3.condition is satisfied for vertices such as v,s,w right?

Comment: No, it is vice versa, if $a,b$ are in $N$ then they are connected to $v$ so we have at least two edges in triangle $abv$. But, since it is impossible to have exactly 2 edges, then $a,b$ are also connected. So all vertices in $N$ are connected.

Comment: Right,  so we only needed second condition. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct interpretation is that a $3$-vertex subgraph induced by $\{u,v,w\}$ is allowed to have no edges, $1$ edge, or all $3$ edges - but not $2$ of the edges.

You can check that this makes the adjacent-or-equal relation between vertices transitive. It is always reflexive and symmetric. Since it is an equivalence relation, it has equivalence classes, which are your complete graph components.